# home page in magento2

Tags: magento2, template, jquery, knockoutjs

I have created home.js file using require-config.js for HomePage.

And init that home.js file in home.phtml file for Home Page.

But i need to get the function that inside the home.js file into size.html file for Home Page.

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {

            xxHomePage: 'XXX_HomePage/js/home-page'
        }
    }
};
```

**In js file:**

```
 getMsg: function () {
            return "HI";
        },
```

**In Home.phtml file:**

```
<div class="home-slider" id="home-slider" data-mage-init='{"xxHomePage":{}}' data-bind="blockLoader:true">
```

I need to get the 'getMsg' function into size.phtml (that also in home page

Is there any possible

How to do this ..

Thanks

Comment: Please share the code of `home.js` and and which function you want to call?

Comment: also Provide require js  code

Answer (score 0):

**Add Below js at size.html**

```
   require([
        'jquery',
        'XXX_HomePage/js/home-page'
    ],function($,homePage){      
        // call your function 

        console.log(homePage.getMsg());
    });
```

Comment: But size.phtml  template is a ko template

Comment: then you  want to call  getMsg on window load ?

Comment: Based on size.phtml 'div' visible in view port

Comment: `Based on size.phtml ` what?

Comment: `shop-by-bra-size` is  sector , when dom will find `data-bind="scope: 'shop-by-bra-size'"` then  `XX_ShopBySize/js/shop-by-size` initilize .https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html

Comment: I need to append the html content into particular div... styleBasedProducts += "<div class='row image-full'><div class='col-md-12 home-title text-center'><div><span class='light'>Style Based</span><span class='heavier'> Products</span></div><p aria-hidden='true'></p></div></div>";

Comment: Also i need to init custom js for '.image-full' class .. How to add that in html content

Comment: i need to frame that html like this <div class="image-full" data-mage-init='{"imageResponsive": {}}'>